# Method called as if it belongs to the class with this parameter suppressed

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following WPF code:

```
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FlowDocument fd = new FlowDocument();
        fd.LoadFromWordML("../../testdoc.docx");
```

FlowDocument (in System.Windows.Documents namespace) **does not** have a LoadFromWordML method.  Rather this method is defined locally as follows:

```
    public static void LoadFromWordML(this FlowDocument doc, string path)
```

Yet as you can see, LoadFromWordML is being called as if it is a method of FlowDocument class, and in fact the 'this' argument is being suppressed.

What C# language facility allows this?  (And a comment against language design: this makes it very difficult to read legacy code.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

> Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise modifying the original type. Extension methods are a special kind of static method, but they are called as if they were instance methods

I have encountered these problems using them

1. Hunting documentation to figure out where the hell they are defined.
2. They cannot be defined to be virtual so it can lead to problems. In one of the projects I worked on we had `Arc` deriving from `Circle`. Somebody decided that `Transform` method should be an extension method. So most of the time it worked. Transforming a `Circle` yielded a transformed `Circle` and same with `Arc`. But it lead to subtle errors when you transformed an `Arc` when it was being used as an `Circle` reference.

Comment: If you're deriving an Arc from a Circle, I think you have a problem already ('is-a' relationship).

Comment: @jv42 With due respect... thats just your opinion

Comment: Thank you Rajkumar.  Your point #1 is exactly what I was faced with here.  Maybe an initial 'this' argument is a give-away that it's an extension method.  But I am just worried that C# is on its way to becoming another unmanageable mess like C++.

Comment: @parapurarajkumar That's also called 'maths', not only an opinion in fact.

Comment: @parapurarajkumar A circle is-a arc, but an arc isn't a circle.

Comment: @jv42 If it was universally agreed , we won't have [Circle-ellipse_problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem).I wasn't trying to convey if arc is circle or vice versa but using extension methods with polymorphism

Comment: @parapurarajkumar I agree about the point, I just feel that the example is controversial.